# Extracting words from Text file (find and replace) using dictionary in Python

Tags: python, file, dictionary, replace, find

I have the following lines in a text file:

```
some text
some text
fields: [orders.date, orders.collection, orders.cancelled, orders.location,
 orders.arrival, orders.country, orders.delivered, orders.colors,
 orders.complete_time, fight.cancelled, fligt.arrival, flight.delayed]
some text 
some text
```

I would like to replace each word after the `'.'` so, for example, `orders.date` should now be `orders.Date_time_stamp`. Similarly, `orders.collection` to be changed to `orders.Collected_at`
Since this is a txt file I am not sure how to surpass the brackets `[]` and then replace each word in it.

I have the words stored as a dictionary so I am using for loop. The key is the old word and value is the new word. For example 'date' is the `key` and Date_time_stamp is the `value.` Similarly, the collection is the key and the value is Collected_at

```
d = {
    'date': 'Date_time_stamp', 
    'collection':'collected_at'
    # And so on...
}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I suggest to make use of regex to extract content inside square brackets, then split given result by comma and then do your action, like iterating by each word, get key and replace it by dict value and replacing it

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: @Shashank I haven't worked with regex before but I will look into it :) Thank you

Comment: @Prune hey thank you for the feedback I actually tried a lot of cases for this one. I have never worked with the regex so I wasn't sure how to solve these specific cases. You can check my other parts in my previous queries

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use a for loop to make your program iterate through your dictionary, and use `re.sub` to replace each key with the corresponding value:

```
import re

d = {'date': 'Date_time_stamp', 'collection':'collected_at'}

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    for k in d:
        text = re.sub(f'.{k}(?!\w)', f'.{d[k]}', text)

with open('text.txt', 'w') as w:
    w.write(text)
```

Before:

```
some text
some text
fields: [orders.date, orders.collection, orders.cancelled, orders.location,
 orders.arrival, orders.country, orders.delivered, orders.colors,
 orders.complete_time, fight.cancelled, fligt.arrival, flight.delayed]
some text 
some text
```

After:

```
some text
some text
fields: [orders.Date_time_stamp, orders.collected_at, orders.cancelled, orders.location,
 orders.arrival, orders.country, orders.delivered, orders.colors,
 orders.complete_time, fight.cancelled, fligt.arrival, flight.delayed]
some text 
some text
```

Comment: hey thank you so much. I wanted to ask if it's a regex function that you used? Where can I best learn them?

Comment: @HamzaShehzad There's no regex involved in the code, just the classic `str.replace` method.

Comment: there is an issue with your solution if I have a d = {'deliver': nono} and in the file I have a text: the parcel is delivered. then based on your code I get the result as the parcel is nonoed - somehow it's replacing deliver with deliver in the word "delivered"

Comment: @HamzaShehzad Updated with regex.

Comment: hey, it doesn't change anything your last solution was more accurate than this one. It doesn't change any key /value. Also, we have to replace the words between the [ ] after the '.' which your first solution was doing fine expect the issue that I mentioned in my above comment

Comment: can you please explain what does this does. it locates the '.' position and then looks for the key ? I am not sure what does the (?!=\w)' does. Would really appreciate if you can explain this  f'.{k}(?!=\w)'

Comment: unfortunately, it gives the same issue as with your first solution i.e it can't differentiate between deliver and delivered it's giving noned for the key deliver even though I only have the key 'delivered'. It replaces the deliver with nono and puts ed at the end

Comment: @HamzaShehzad `f'.{k}(?!\w)'` finds all the substrings that begins with a dot (`'.'`), the key in the middle (`'{k}'`), and cannot end with a word character (`'(?!\w)'`).

Comment: @HamzaShehzad If the strings to replace don't always begin with a dot, try changing the regex string to `f'\b{k}\b'`.

Comment: They do begin with a dot. I have a dictionary = {'deliver': xxx} and if I run the code above and run it in a file that has a line:  orders. cancellation, orders.delivered. Then, as a result: I get orders,xxxed - which means somehow it's finding deliver in every word - the word 'delivered' in this case and just replacing it with xxx along with the 'ed' in delivered' which should not happen